# How can I add dynamic variable in the URL which being used inside requests.get()?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

I would like to add dynamic variable in the below URL-

```
book_id = 33327 

resp_data = requests.get('http://example.com/book_id')
```

How can achieve this in Django 1.9.6 (Python 2.7)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple:

```
book_id = 33327
resp_data = requests.get('http://example.com/{}'.format(book_id))
```

The above example works for both Python 2 and 3. With Python 2 you can also use:

```
resp_data = requests.get('http://example.com/%s' % book_id)
```

Comment: % formatting is still perfectly well supported in Python 3, and is not deprecated.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am not sure if it still recommended to use `%` over `format()` with Python 3. Could you confirm?

Comment: Perhaps not deprecated, but the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) hint that `format` is *preferred*. "Note The formatting operations described here exhibit a variety of quirks that lead to a number of common errors (such as failing to display tuples and dictionaries correctly). Using the newer str.format() interface helps avoid these errors, and also provides a generally more powerful, flexible and extensible approach to formatting text."

Comment: Of course, in this case, you could skip the format() and just do `requests.get('http://example.com/' + str(book_id))`